# Problem with referencing a drive with spaces in its label

Tags: mount, usb-drive, clone

the problem...

My external HDD on a USB port is listed as device `/dev/sdc` with partition 1 of that drive `/dev/sdc1` mounted on `/media/mark/Seagate Expansion Drive`.

The problem is the spaces, I can't write anything to the drive, it results in an error.

I need to be able to use `cat` or `dd` to pipe to zip (with preference) and store the compressed file on the `/media/mark/Seagate Expansion Drive`.

Suggestions on other methods of accessing the drive, I have tried changing the drive label but that results in a warning and it won't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct, best solution would be changing the label of the disk. I too had problem with some disk and needed to do that in Windows (grrrr).

Two solutions:

1. learn to quote the filenames correctly:

   ```
    ls "/media/mark/Seagate Expansion Drive/"
   ```

   (notice the `"`) will work. See also http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-quoting or http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#spaces, and yes, spaces in file names are evil.

   So for example to write to file in the disk you need to use

   ```
   dd if=something of="/media/mark/Seagate Expansion Drive/file.out"
   ```

   or whatever you are using.
2. create a symbolic link

   ```
    ln -s "/media/mark/Seagate Expansion Drive/" /media/mark/mydisk
   ```

   and use now `/media/mark/mydisk`. It will work 99% of the cases... if you take care to not use it when the disk is not mounted.

What **does not** work is trying to rename the mountpoint with `mv`:

```
 sudo mv "/media/mark/Seagate Expansion Drive/" /media/mark/mydisk
 mv: cannot move ‘/media/mark/Seagate Expansion Drive/’ to ‘/media/mark/mydisk’: Device or resource busy
```

because a mount-point semantics are quite different from a plain directory.

Comment: nice one, not one of the examples I had seen wrapped that device name and path in quotes, all I had ever been shown as example was an unquoted string. I will look at symbolic links later, bit of a learning curve here, you know, old dog, new tricks, be gentle... :)

Comment: You can also "escape" spaces which would look like `/media/mark/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/`.  @Rmano: `gparted` can handle spaces in file names nowadays...  ;-)